# Pointers, dereferencing and referencing

Tags: c, pointers

I declare a pointer like this:

```
char *ptr = "hello";
```

and when I do this

```
printf("%p\n", *&*&ptr);
```

the result is address of that pointer, but when I do this

```
printf("%s\n", *&*&ptr);
```

the result is hello.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Because `%p` specifies pointers, `%s` specified strings and `*&*&` does exactly nothing

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What are you trying to determine here by using `*&*&`? And why would it be a surprise what `%p` prints versus `%s` prints if you read the documentation for these format specifiers? And do you understand what `&` and `*` mean in this context?

Comment: And what does the backslash `\\` do?

Comment: @Klaimmore ?? The only backslash is in `\n`.

Comment: @klaimmore that's a typo I introduced by mistake while editing. Fixed.

Comment: The first result is **not** the address of `ptr`, it *is* the address of `"hello"`, which is the value in `ptr`. If you want the address of `ptr`, use `&ptr`.

Comment: @WeatherVane if you check the edits, Frederico edited and deleted the backslash that was in the original question. The OP had `\*&*&ptr` rather than `*&*&ptr`, oddly...

Comment: &*&* was a part of the code I found on the Internet, and I know that it does nothing. I was wondering why %s prints hello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*&*&ptr` is a weird way of writing `ptr` (since `*` cancels out `&`).

`%p` expects a pointer, and prints the value of the pointer (i.e. the address to which it points). The value of `ptr` is therefore a valid input, and you are seeing the expected result.

`%s` expects a pointer to a NUL-terminated sequence of `char` values, and prints those `char` values (but not the NUL). The value of `ptr` is therefore a valid input, and you are seeing the expected result.